# react hook can not clear input value

Tags: reactjs

my component look like this

```
const onkeychange = async (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, textValue: e.target.value })
    if (delay !== false) {
        clearTimeout(delay)
    }
    let string = e.target.value
    if (string.trim() == '') {
        setState({ ...state, issearching: false })
    }
}
<input
    type="text"
    autoComplete="off"
    name="search"
    placeholder="Search for a Product, Brand or Category"
    value={state.textValue}
    className="search"
    onChange={onkeychange}
/>
```

problem is, When after I type something in the input. Then try to delete everything, I can't I can delete all but one last character. For exmaple: I type `hello` in the input. trying to delete it with backspace, I can remove `ello` but not the h

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if `string === ''` and case `true` you're setting the `state` using the old `state` which includes `string`'s value just before deleting the last char, this is why you can't delete the last one. You should remove the `condition`

```
const onkeychange = async (e) => {
    setState({ ...state, textValue: e.target.value })
    if (delay !== false) 
        clearTimeout(delay)

}
```

Comment: I need that condition

Comment: Your condition ensures that `textValue` will never be empty. This is a wanted behavior? Case not, what is the expect behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Use functional form of `setState` to get the latest state when updating it. Also I'd recommend to consider using reducer hook here.

```
  const onkeychange = async e => {
    const value = e.target ? e.target.value : "";
    setState(currentState => ({ ...currentState, textValue: value }));
    if (delay !== false) {
        clearTimeout(delay)
    }

    if (value.trim() === "") {
      setState(currentState => ({ ...currentState, issearching: false }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` is async, you can use a callback in the setState to get the correct preState to solve this problem.

```
const string = e.target.value;

setState((prevState) => {
   return { ...prevState, textValue: string }
})

if (delay !== false) {
   clearTimeout(delay)
}

if (string.trim() === '') {
   setState((prevState) => {
     return ({ ...prevState, isSearching: false })
    })
}
```

or a more simple way is to only run setState once.

```
 const string = e.target.value
 if (delay !== false) {
      clearTimeout(delay);
 }
 const isSearching = string.trim() !== "";
 setState({ ...state, textValue: string, isSearching});
```

[view demo on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-moore-bjqwe)